# How to store 4 32 bit floats into one 128 bit xmm register?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, sse, simd

I want to store 4 32 bit floats into xmm0 where each of these floats is stored in one 128 bit register.
For example I have 4 floats:
xmm1: 10.2
xmm2: 5.8
xmm3: 9.3
xmm4: 12.7 (each only using 32 bits of the 128 bit register)
and want them to be stored into xmm0 like that: 
10.2, 5.8, 9.3, 12.7
So that they are stored next to them inside of xmm0.

Then I also would like to extract each of them separately after I have done some math on xmm0 (e.g. mulps ..)

I've tried using movlps and movhps, but they use only memory to load from and not a 128 bit register as source. I wouldn't like to use any additional memory due to performance.

PSLLDQ might help, but is there a better solution for my problem?

Comment: `PSLLD` doesn't do what you think it does. It does not shift the doublewords themselves, it shifts the bits inside each doubleword. Try `SHUFPS` or `PSLLDQ` instead.

Comment: [I asked GCC and clang to do it](https://godbolt.org/z/SDR4Ov). They merge `xmm1..4` into `xmm0`. Both use 3 instructions and each one should use port 5 with 1c lat/tput (but I've only skimmed the Agner Fog's table and only for SklX). However gcc one only uses the SSE extension if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Why aren't you using the intrinsic that does exactly that?

Comment: @Jester Thank you for pointing that out. I'm still a beginner and have some problems using Intel Manual. That might solve my problem.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thats also quite interesting, but I'm trying to avoid any AVX instructions

Comment: `unpcklps` as well as `movlhps` can take memory or another register as second argument. If you don't want AVX instructions, just take @MargaretBloom's link and replace `-march=cannonlake` by `-msse` (or `-msse4.2`, or whatever instruction set you prefer): https://godbolt.org/z/ruhVhl

Comment: @MargaretBloom: I'm not aware of any way to beat 3 port5 uops with SSE/AVX2.  By far the most obvious way is 2x `unpcklps` + `unpcklpd` or `movlhps`.  But now that you mention it, possibly you could set up for the 3rd instruction being an efficient `blendps` immediate if you can use `shufps` to get your inputs into `[abxx]` `[xxcd]`, or perhaps actually possible: `[axcx]` `[xbxd]` (because the low 2 elements of shufps output comes from the first source=dst, the other half comes from the other source.)  x86-64 GCC uses baseline x86-64 by default, which is SSE1 + SSE2.

Comment: @pedzer: look at compiler output for `_mm_set_ps(f3,f2,f1,f0)`.  Or look at Agner Fog's optimization guide: he has a chapter on SSE/AVX with a handy table of data-movement instruction by type.  https://agner.org/optimize/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Look at [compiler output for `_mm_set_ps(f3,f2,f1,f0)`](https://godbolt.org/z/RTkIK6)** or for `_mm_setr_ps(f0,f1,f2,f3)` with your choice of tune and `-march` options.

Or look at [**Agner Fog's optimization guide**](https://agner.org/optimize/): he has a chapter on SSE/AVX with a handy table of data-movement instruction by type.  Great for learning your way around which shuffles are available in the highly non-orthogonal SSE/AVX extensions.

---

As people have pointed out, the standard way is 2x `unpcklps` to merge pairs into vectors of `[00ba]` `[00dc]` where `0` is a don't-care value or actually `0.0` if the upper elements of your scalar floats happened to be zero.  (My notation follows the Intel convention from diagrams of having the high element at the *left*, so left shifts move data to the left in your notation, and looking at your data with different element widths don't change how you write it.)

Then `movlhps` to copy the low qword of one xmm register to the high qword of another (merging into the existing value).

If this wasn't obvious and well-known to you, you should be writing in C with intrinsics, and looking at the optimized compiler output to learn the basic ways.  clang has a very good shuffle optimizer that can find better ways to implement the logic of your intrinsics into asm.

---

#### There may be a better way:

Those 3 instructions are all shuffles, and on Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs are limited to 1 per clock throughput (competing for port 5).

If we have SSE4.1 available for `blendps` (with an immediate blend-control), we might be able to use that as the final step instead of a shuffle.  It can run on any port.

I think we can use [`shufps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/shufps) to create vectors of `[0c0a]` and `[d0b0]`.  The low 2 elements of `shufps` output comes from the first source=dst operand, the other half comes from the other source.

If your input vectors were actually zero-extended with definitely no high garbage, you can use SSE1 `orps` instead of a blend to get `[dcba]`